# Setup shared web hosting for my VMs

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, vmware

I recently started virtualising some stuff, but I've run into a problem. 
I want to have multiple (sub)domains pointing at different IPs on my network. This used to be doable by opening different ports to different machines, but now I need to have two different domains pointing to two different machines on my network on port 80. I don't know if DNS is the solution or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to run a proxy internally - have the port opened to one machine acting as a gateway with something like ngnix (which is better for things using websockets and other fancy things) or lighttpd (which is simpler).. Essentially you open the port to the proxy server, and have that distribute traffic as needed.

I don't actually have a ngnix install to test (sorry!) but something like

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
    }
}
```

Ought to work with some tweaks. I based it off this excellent guide

I have it set up on lighttpd (which is inefficient) and the config block looks like

```
$HTTP["host"] =="test.example.com" {
proxy.server = ( "" => ((
                          "host" => "192.168.1.1",
                          "port" => "8000"
                        ))
                 )
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works for my Gitlab instance but not for my nextcloud. I've been trying to forward it using this: `server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  cloud.prjctdesign.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.178.32;
    }
}`
But it doesn't work. Do I need to regenerate the SSL certificate or is something wrong in my forwarding?